# How to add file collection record programatically in custom extension in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions

I want to add the file collection record programatically in a custom record I have created in the backend.

I can add separate files right now after I created a custom model which had the file property, but I cannot control which folder it goes to right now, so I want to instead make a file collection type of record inside my custom model so I can have more control over which folder the file gets uploaded.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone else stumbles upon this, here is how I did it.

```
'files'            => [
        'exclude' => 0,
        'label'   => 'Files',
        'config'  => \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::getFileFieldTCAConfig( 'files',
            [
                'appearance'           => [
                    'createNewRelationLinkTitle' => 'LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xlf:images.addFileReference',
                ],
                // custom configuration for displaying fields in the overlay/reference table
                // to use the imageoverlayPalette instead of the basicoverlayPalette
                'foreign_match_fields' => [
                    'fieldname'   => 'files',
                    'tablenames'  => 'tx_table_name',
                    'table_local' => 'sys_file',
                ],
            ] ),
    ],
```